# How to connect from our own application to in-built alarm in iphone?

Tags: ios, alarm

I have developed one application. In that, i need to setup alarm everyday or selected days. It should be repeat up to changes by us again. So i took one button in my app for in-built iphone alarm window. Once i click the button, in-built alarm should come in my app. So would you please help me for this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [local notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to set up alarms

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to Access  build Alarm in iOS Devices.

The only way to create Local Notifications are used to create Alarm Apps in iOS.